# How can I use a std::valarray to store/manipulate a contiguous 2D array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, std

How can I use a `std::valarray` to store/manipulate a 2D array?

I'd like to see an example of a 2D array with elements accessed by row/column indices. Something like this pseudo code:

```
matrix(i,j) = 42;
```

An example of how to initialize such an array would also be nice.

I'm already aware of Boost.MultiArray, Boost.uBlas, and Blitz++.

Feel free to answer why I shouldn't use valarray for my use case. However, I want the memory for the multidimensional array to be a contiguous (columns x rows) block. No Java-style nested arrays.

Comment: Why would you want to use valarray? I haven't seen it in use anywhere and only know of arguments against its use.

Comment: @gf: I'm quite happy with boost for "dynamic" multidimensional arrays. But I stumbled upon valarray somewhere else in SO, and was curious on how it could be used for multi-dimensional arrays. Online examples on using valarray (particularly for my use case) seem scarce.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche what are the arguments against using it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
template <class element_type>
class matrix
{
public:
    matrix(size_t width, size_t height): m_stride(width), m_height(height), m_storage(width*height) {  }

    element_type &operator()(size_t row, size_t column)
    {
        // column major
        return m_storage[std::slice(column, m_height, m_stride)][row];

        // row major
        return m_storage[std::slice(row, m_stride, m_height)][column];
    }

private:
    std::valarray<element_type> m_storage;
    size_t m_stride;
    size_t m_height;
};
```

`std::valarray` provides many interesting ways to access elements, via slices, masks, multidimentional slices, or an indirection table. See `std::slice_array`, `std::gslice_array`, `std::mask_array`, and `std::indirect_array` for more details.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. That's what I was looking for. I especially like that you showed both row/column major access.

Comment: Is the valarray data guaranteed to be contiguous, like vector?

Comment: From MSDN: The template class describes an object that controls a sequence of elements of type Type that are stored as an array, designed for performing high-speed mathematical operations, and optimized for computational performance.  


So, I would assume so.

Comment: @MSN There is an error in your ctor, you have two m_stride. `m_stride(width), m_stride(height)`

Comment: @MSN: Which compiler/stdlib were you using such that `matrix::operator()` compiled?  On my copy of gcc 4.4.5 `slice_array<T>` (as returned by `valarray<T>::operator[slice slc]`) doesn't seem to have an `operator[]`.  [Here's what I was trying](http://pastebin.com/YVa9CUGD).  The [`clang` demo site](http://llvm.org/demo/) also chokes on it.

Comment: @genpfault, I never compiled it. Which looking at the documentation for slice_array means this just won't work, although returning gslice_array would.

Comment: @MSN the answer is not correct - slice_array/gslice_array do not imply per-element access (as far as I understand these classes were aimed for SIMD operation). On the other side, one can "effectively" assign a row (at a specified stride) of values from another valarray.

Comment: Yes, as @genpfault mentioned, I'm able to use slice as a column accessor, but not as a row accessor. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Good answer, it would be great if you also add a note that he can implement `operators` as desired to perform the necessary operations on the whole matrix `m_storage`, like `operator+` or others as he needs. Also worth noting that implementing row/column based operations will have to rely on old techniques given the use of 1 `valarray` for the entire matrix.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

using namespace std;

typedef valarray<valarray<int> > va2d;

int main()
{
    int data[][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
    va2d mat(valarray<int>(3), 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
           mat[ i ][ j ] = data[ i ][ j ];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
           cout << mat[ i ][ j ] << endl;
}
```

More on `valarray`:

- It is optimized for numeric computation.
- It is a `vector` like container with special member functions for slicing and dicing.
- No iterators
- Designed for vector machines and perform poorly on current ones: `vector` access may be faster
- Was not supported by all compilers (check the documentation)  / poorly implemented
- See 26.1 for the types that can be used as a parameter to `valarray<T>`: E.g:

> 3 In addition, many member and related
>   functions of valarray can be
>   successfully instantiated and will
>   exhibit well-defined behavior if and
>   only if T satisfies additional
>   requirements specified for each such
>   member or related function.
>
> 4 [
>   Example: It is valid to instantiate
>   valarray, but operator>()
>   will not be successfully instantiated
>   for valarray operands, since
>   complex does not have any ordering
>   operators. —end example ]

Edit#2: The standard gurantees that `vector`, like arrays, always use contiguous memory. Also, we have:

> **26.5.2 Class template valarray**
>
> 1 The class template valarray is a
>   one-dimensional smart array, with
>   elements numbered sequentially from
>   zero. It is a representation of the
>   mathematical concept of an ordered set
>   of values. The illusion of higher
>   dimensionality may be produced by the
>   familiar idiom of computed indices,
>   together with the powerful
>   subsetting capabilities provided by
>   the generalized subscript operators.

and further:

> **26.5.2.3 valarray element access**
>
> 4 Likewise, the expression &a[i] !=
>   &b[j] evaluates as true for any two
>   arrays a and b and for any size_t i
>   and size_t j such that i is less than
>   the length of a and j is less than the
>   length of b. This property indicates
>   an absence of aliasing and may be used
>   to advantage by optimizing compilers.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Didn't clarify my question fast enough. +1 anyways.

Comment: `valarray` is intended to contain multidimensional arrays without nesting. `valarray<valarray<...> >` should only be necessary for an array of matrices/arrays of different sizes.

Comment: dirkgently answered before I clarified that I wanted contiguous memory. No need to downvote.

Comment: From the quotes you posted, it's not clear to me if the valarray data is guaranteed to be contiguous. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In valarray<T>, the type T has some constraints (not enforced by the compiler). T cannot be a valarray, according to this http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2000-q1/msg00123.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test for the multidimensional array to be a contiguous (columns x rows) block. You can see this example with **valarray**.

```
template<class T>
class Array: public std::valarray<T> {
  size_t row,col; 
public:
  Array(){}
  Array(size_t nx) : std::valarray<T>(nx){row=nx,col=1;}
  Array(size_t nx, size_t ny) : std::valarray<T>(nx*ny){row=nx,col=ny;}
  virtual ~Array(){}
  T& operator()(size_t i,size_t j) { return (*this)[i*col+j];}
  size_t Size(size_t n) const { return (n<2) ? col: row;}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any of the other responses particularly helpful so I thought I'd chip in with a solution I found. The top answer is kinda there, but as far as I can tell, there is no default way to index a slice. I don't know for the life of me why this isn't a feature but here's what you can do to make it work.

If you add a new class that extends slice_array you can give it an indexer method.

```
class slice_darray : slice_array<double> {
public:
    double& operator[](size_t idx){ return _Data(start() + idx * stride());}
};
```

Once you've done that you can just change the function in @MSN's post to something like

```
slice_darray& operator[](size_t row) { return (slice_darray&)(m_storage[std::slice(row * m_rows, m_rows, 1)]);
```

And that should give you the behavior you want. You should be able to access the matrix by doing something like M[row][col]

Comment: What is `_Data`? Is it a member of `std::slice_array<T>` in your particular standard library?

Comment: Oh, I understand now. `_Data` is reference to the original `valarray`. It's too bad `slice_array` already has this reference and you end up holding it twice in your extension class. Still, a clever workaround.

Comment: No, I still don't understand. You don't pass a reference/pointer to the original `valarray` when constructing your `slice_darray`. You're also returning a dangling reference in your second `operator[]`.

Comment: Yea agree, should be avoided

Comment: The slice gets a reference to the valarry when its initialized as an indexer. So val[slice(a,b,c)]. The solution I wrote here is tested and works perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

[Here's](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_202.html) an example that includes a bit of matrix manipulation

Comment: Could you at least include a short example that addresses the question? External sites might be down at some point.

Comment: I dont seem to be able to find a 2D `valarray` part in that example but a 2D matrix flattened out. I think the OP wants a `valarray< valarray <T> >` thingy.

Comment: @dirkgently: I want the array memory to be contiguous, so no valarray< valarray <T> >. Edited question.